# Is there a way to get average of returned numbers in twig?

Tags: twig

I have this in my twig template the returns an array of rated numbers like 5 4 5 3 2

```
{% for star in ad.ratings %}

    <p style="font-size: 15px">{{ star.rating }}</p>

    {% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to get just the average of the returned numbers in twig?

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
{% set sum = 0 %}
{% for star in ad.ratings %}
  {% set sum= sum+ ad.value %}
{% endfor %}
{% set avg = sum/ad.ratings |length %}
average: {{  avg }}
```